# Where is the pulled Docker image configuration file

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I pulled

```
docker pull dylanmei/zeppelin:latest
docker run --name zeppelin -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 dymanmei/zeppelin:latest
```

If I want to change the port of the zeppelin web-site, where do I find the zeppelin configure files?

> d91ecdff6a24        dylanmei/zeppelin:latest
> "bin/zeppelin.sh"        26 seconds ago      Up 26 seconds
> 0.0.0.0:8088-8089->8088-8089/tcp                           zeppelin

This is my `docker ps -a` information. Where is the Docker configuration file of zeppelin?

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin's configuration is somewhere within the image that you downloaded. However, your question asks how you may configure the port(s) on which Zeppelin is accessed and, using the container, this is straightforward.

The `docker run ...` command that you included defines 2 ports mappings. These are defined with the flags`-p 8080:8080` and `-p 8081:8081`.. These define that your host's port 8080 is mapped to the container's port 8080  and your host's port 8081 to the container's port 8081.

Rather then change the ports used by the container (and configured within it), you may simple change these port mappings when you run the container.

For example, if you use `-p 8888:8080`, the container's port 8080 (unchanged) would now be available on your host's port 8888 (instead of 8080).

This has the effect you wanted of changing the port.